# for loop not behaving correctly in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, quantization

I'm working on a program where I have to quantize a sine wave in MATLAB with 16 quantization levels

I have developed a for loop that should quantize the values properly, and it does for the positive values of the sine wave, but then displays all zeros for the negative values of the signal

Here is the code I have developed:

```
sig1 = [0 0.6428 0.9848 0.8660 0.3420 -0.3420 -0.8660 -0.9848 -0.6428 -0.0000]

b = 4;
N = 10;

yMax = 1.4088;
yMin = -1.3660;

for i = 1:N
value = ((yMax - yMin)/(2^b));

halfstep = value / 2;

%Calculating quantization levels
value0 = value * 0;
value1 = value * 1;
value2 = value * 2;
value3 = value * 3;
value4 = value * 4;
value5 = value * 5;
value6 = value * 6;
value7 = value * 7;
value8 = value * -1;
value9 = value * -2;
value10 = value * -3;
value11 = value * -4;
value12 = value * -5;
value13 = value * -6;
value14 = value * -7;
value15 = value * -8;

%Quantizing signal1
if value15 < sig1(i) < value14
    if sig1(i) < value15 + halfstep
        qsig1(i) = -8;
    else
        qsig1(i) = -7;
    end
elseif value14 < sig1(i) < value13
    if sig1(i) < value14 + halfstep
        qsig1(i) = -7;
    else
        qsig1(i) = -6;
    end
elseif value13 < sig1(i) < value12
    if sig1(i) < value13 + halfstep
        qsig1(i) = -6;
    else
        qsig1(i) = -5;
    end
elseif value12 < sig1(i) < value11
    if sig1(i) < value12 + halfstep
        qsig1(i) = -5;
    else
        qsig1(i) = -4;
    end
elseif value11 < sig1(i) < value10
    if sig1(i) < value11 + halfstep
        qsig1(i) = -4;
    else
        qsig1(i) = -3;
    end
elseif value10 < sig1(i) < value9
    if sig1(i) < value10 + halfstep
        qsig1(i) = -3;
    else
        qsig1(i) = -2;
    end
elseif value9 < sig1(i) < value8
    if sig1(i) < value9 + halfstep
        qsig1(i) = -2;
    else
        qsig1(i) = -1;
    end
elseif value8 < sig1(i) < value0
    if sig1(i) < value8 + halfstep
        qsig1(i) = -1;
    else
        qsig1(i) = 0;
    end
elseif value0 < sig1(i) < value1
    if sig1(i) < value0 + halfstep
        qsig1(i) = 0;
    else
        qsig1(i) = 1;
    end
elseif value1 < sig1(i) < value2
    if sig1(i) < value1 + halfstep
        qsig1(i) = 1;
    else
        qsig1(i) = 2;
    end
elseif value2 < sig1(i) < value3
    if sig1(i) < value2 + halfstep
        qsig1(i) = 2;
    else
        qsig1(i) = 3;
    end
elseif value3 < sig1(i) < value4
    if sig1(i) < value3 + halfstep
        qsig1(i) = 3;
    else
        qsig1(i) = 4;
    end
elseif value4 < sig1(i) < value5
    if sig1(i) < value4 + halfstep
        qsig1(i) = 4;
    else
        qsig1(i) = 5;
    end
elseif value5 < sig1(i) < value6
    if sig1(i) < value5 + halfstep
        qsig1(i) = 5;
    else
        qsig1(i) = 6;
    end
 elseif value6 < sig1(i) < value7
    if sig1(i) < value6 + halfstep
        qsig1(i) = 6;
    else
        qsig1(i) = 7;
    end
elseif sig1(i) < value15
        qsig1(i) = 0;
end
end

sig1
qsig1
```

If anyone can help me figure out why the negative values of sig1 are being made all zeros in qsig1 I would appreciate it!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After more working, I discovered that MATLAB can't do two comparisons as well as I thought it could so I used and statements to achieve the desired result.

Code I used:

```
if sig1(i) < value15
    qsig1(i) = -8;
elseif sig1(i) < value14 && sig1(i) > value15
    if value15 < sig1(i) && sig1(i) < (value15 + halfstep)
        qsig1(i) = -8;
    else
        qsig1(i) = -7;
    end
elseif sig1(i) < value13 && sig1(i) > value14
    if value14 < sig1(i) && sig1(i) < (value14 + halfstep)
        qsig1(i) = -7;
    else
        qsig1(i) = -6;
    end
elseif sig1(i) < value12 && sig1(i) > value13
    if value13 < sig1(i) && sig1(i) < (value13 + halfstep)
        qsig1(i) = -6;
    else
        qsig1(i) = -5;
    end
elseif sig1(i) < value11 && sig1(i) > value12
    if value12 < sig1(i) && sig1(i) < (value12 + halfstep)
        qsig1(i) = -5;
    else
        qsig1(i) = -4;
    end
elseif sig1(i) < value10 && sig1(i) > value11
    if value11 < sig1(i) && sig1(i) < (value11 + halfstep)
        qsig1(i) = -4;
    else
        qsig1(i) = -3;
    end
elseif sig1(i) < value9 && sig1(i) > value10
    if value10 < sig1(i) && sig1(i) < (value10 + halfstep)
        qsig1(i) = -3;
    else
        qsig1(i) = -2;
    end
elseif sig1(i) < value8 && sig1(i) > value9
    if value9 < sig1(i) && sig1(i) < (value9 + halfstep)
        qsig1(i) = -2;
    else
        qsig1(i) = -1;
    end
elseif sig1(i) < value0 && sig1(i) > value8
    if value8 < sig1(i) && sig1(i) < (value8 + halfstep)
        qsig1(i) = -1;
    else
        qsig1(i) = 0;
    end
elseif sig1(i) < value1 && sig1(i) > value0
    if value0 < sig1(i) && sig1(i) < (value0 + halfstep)
        qsig1(i) = 0;
    else
        qsig1(i) = 1;
    end
elseif sig1(i) < value2 && sig1(i) > value1
    if value1 < sig1(i) && sig1(i) < (value1 + halfstep)
        qsig1(i) = 1;
    else
        qsig1(i) = 2;
    end
elseif sig1(i) < value3 && sig1(i) > value2
    if value2 < sig1(i) && sig1(i) < (value2 + halfstep)
        qsig1(i) = 2;
    else
        qsig1(i) = 3;
    end
elseif sig1(i) < value4 && sig1(i) > value3
    if value3 < sig1(i) && sig1(i) < (value3 + halfstep)
        qsig1(i) = 3;
    else
        qsig1(i) = 4;
    end
elseif sig1(i) < value5 && sig1(i) > value4
    if value4 < sig1(i) && sig1(i) < (value4 + halfstep)
        qsig1(i) = 4;
    else
        qsig1(i) = 5;
    end
elseif sig1(i) < value6 && sig1(i) > value5
    if value5 < sig1(i) && sig1(i) < (value5 + halfstep)
        qsig1(i) = 5;
    else
        qsig1(i) = 6;
    end
 elseif sig1(i) < value7 && sig1(i) > value6
    if value6 < sig1(i) && sig1(i) < (value6 + halfstep)
        qsig1(i) = 6;
    else
        qsig1(i) = 7;
    end
elseif value7 < sig1(i)
        qsig1(i) = 7;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your decision is very over complicated. Try to use function **round** :

```
sig1 = [0 0.6428 0.9848 0.8660 0.3420 -0.3420 -0.8660 -0.9848 -0.6428 -0.0000]
b = 4;
N = 10;
yMax = 1.4088;
yMin = -1.3660;
value = ((yMax - yMin)/(2^b));
gsig1=round(sig1./value);
```